# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY an android emulator proplem

Tags: android, google-maps

[2010-03-04 11:50:15 - AndroidSamples]Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

when i uses the

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
..
</application>
```

please do reply me

Comment: You need to provide more information and context for your problem, otherwise it will be very difficult for anyone to thoroughly respond.

Answer (score 23):

Check to make sure that you run on a google api emulator.

Comment: THIS is the way to give an answer!  NOT THIS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7168399/229780

Answer (score 2):

To run on Google API emulator, open your Android SDK & AVD Manager > Available packages > Google Repos > select those Google API levels that you need to test on.

After installing them, add them as virtual device and run.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your project target in Eclipse (or in your `default.properties`) has 'Google APIs' in the name, indicating that you're compiling with the Google APIs Add-On.

Also make sure you've set the correct `<uses-library>` element in your manifest:

```
<application android:name="MyApplication">
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
  ...
</application>
```

For more information on the Google APIs Add-On and using Maps, see this link:

- http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/maps-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I had an apk which i had to install on AVD 4.3 
but installation failed due to INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

All i had to to was 
Go android sdk manager -> extras and then install all of the libraries present in that (like android support library etc)

then restart emulator and installation must be fine