# Android Application

Tags: android

When i run the app. I am getting this error.
[INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] when installing the application.

Comment: **I can guess your application is probably using GoogleMaps. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377284/install-failed-missing-shared-library-an-android-emulator-proplem)**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using a library that you didn't include in the build path.
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary