# ADK - USB - Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android

I am trying to run the ADK demo kit code and implement it on my samsung galaxy s 4g that has been updated to firmware version - 2.3.4.  The project is called "DemoKitLaunch" and can be downloaded on the "Download" link from the following page, under the topic of [Installing the Arduino software and necessary libraries](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html#running-demokit).  I have created new project from existing source, made sure that I have the installed and set the project build target of "Google APIs - 2.3.3". The project is able to build and I can run the project on the emulator.  However, when trying to run it on my phone I get the error of "INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY" in the logcat.

I found that there are many map projects that are having this problem, but I could only find [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377284/install-failed-missing-shared-library-an-android-emulator-proplem) that talks about a similar issue with the usb and the ADK.  In that case the OP was trying to run on a device that was vs. 2.3.3.  Mine is 2.3.4 and I am having the problem.

I have made sure that the manifest has included the "".

I have also built and tried to run the microchip version demo project with the same results.  Code can be found [here](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2919&param=en546070).

Any suggestions on resolving the issue?

Any way to verify that my phone hardware is compatible with the ADK hardware requirements?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

We even found the same error. For that you require to do two steps. First you need to copy two files in our mobile using folowing steps:
adb push android.hardware.usb.accessory.xml /system/etc/permissions/

adb push com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar /system/framework

but to do that first you have to do second step. you have to be root, once you rooted your phone remount your system folder and then do the first step.
http://lgallardo.com/en/2011/03/13/remontar-partici%C3%B3n-system-de-android-en-modo-rw/

The jar and xml file you can pull from google api-10 sdk

We are using Samsung galaxy S. But doing all steps also we are unable to put the mobile in accessory mode. So we are even unsure that samsung galaxy S supports accessory mode or not.

Comment: Interesting.  I was wondering if the correct API's were intalled on my 2.3.4 build.  I am using firmware 2.3.4 KG4 build.  I know that there is a KG6 now available, but I am having problems with my bootloader running properly.

Comment: I just got off the phone with samsung and stated that the T959V SGS4g does support accessory mode.  However, they also stated that the official firmware available from samsung is 2.2.  They said that they are working on an official release of 2.3.4 after they have tested all compatibility.  As we know we can load the leaked version, but I wonder if it is lacking beyond pushing the usb.jar file?

Comment: @fragment: You could finally succeed with this issue?