# can't find com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar

Tags: android

I'am looking for this file to work with Android ADK Demo. This Link [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851430/adk-usb-installation-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library) tells me where to find this file. But I have not enough experience to find the com.android.future.usb.accessory.jar  in order to push this file to the phone. Can someone tell me how to get this file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes with the SDK. Install the SDK and install the package "Google API" (for Android 2.3.3 level 10) in the following path:

> \android-sdk-windows\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10\libs

Comment: Hello again, I found only an executable usb.jar file in this directory. Hint??

Comment: Now you need to push this file to the /system/framework folder and an xml file with the following content you can see in the first answer for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024801/usb-accessory-api-on-samsung-galaxy-s2-android) question into the /system/etc/permissions/

Comment: Hmmm, the xml was already in the etc/permissions and I copied the >usb.jar<  in system/framework folder  (also restart..). Still the same error. Is usb.jar the same as com.android.future.usb.accessory ? (Note: I'am working with Desire HD and this [rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=16819368#post16819368) at the moment.

Comment: Well the HTC Desire HD usually doesn't need a custom ROM... I'm running a Desire HD with version 2.3.4 unrooted without any problems. Are you aware that the link you posted mentions a ROM for the HTC Sensation? I'm not familiar with custom roms but it could be an issue.

Comment: It was the same error with the original Rom and the reason to try a custom rom(I'am also new to custom roms :-( ... ). But the original rom was 2.3.3 and the message "there are no updates available for your phone". I think I try to find an original rom with 2.3.4  and test this. But I have a lack of knowledge of this topic ...

Comment: Well 2.3.3 doesn't support Android Open Accessory. Try this [rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1382235)

Comment: Thanks to user1176976! It's working now! I flash this [" "offical" rom Android 3.3.5 /Sense 3.0 "](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1382235) and both files are already in the directory (.xml + .jar). So now it's working in accessory mode! Thank You so much :-)