# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error while running google map

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error is taking place while i am trying to run the Google map in my android emulator and the app is being crashed. I have tried importing Google map libraries and even added

```
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in my manifest file. 
 There isn't any error in java and XML file. Its an emergency ,what should be done to accomplish it? Thanks in advanced

Comment: delete the bin folder and clean the project. Then again add the google play service library

Answer (score 0):

which map version are you using ??
What have you tried as an solution for this.
Go through below links:

Possible duplicate of [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android) and [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY an android emulator proplem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377284/install-failed-missing-shared-library-an-android-emulator-proplem)