# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android

I keep getting this when I try install my app to the real phone.

E/PackageManager(   67): Package com.mobile.prototype requires unavailable share
d library com.google.android.maps; failing!

The problem is solved when I use the google API emulator. The problem what is my app is eventually going to run on a phone and not an emulator.

Anyone has any solutions?

Comment: Did you try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Comment: I realize this is 2 years later, but what device were you trying to install it on?  Did it have the Google Maps apis in there?  I know devices like the Kindle don't, so you have to do some checking.  What was your solution?