# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android 2.2 API Level 8

Tags: android, android-emulator

maybe somebody can help me out. i'm trying to add a google maps within my android app. if i want to run my app in emulator, i get the error: "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY". of course i read about what my problem, the reason seems to be that the target device doesn't have the needed libs, but i'm not able to solve my problem :-(

in my manifest i've set the permissions:

**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"**

Additionally i defined the maps lib under my application-tag:

**uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"**

Furthermore i obtained an api maps key for my certificate md5-key and use this in my layout:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="07ldFF5M8bvwFSB2DeeUIIvOhyKLNpWkFlTbS6w"/>
```

i don't think that my problem is within my app, could it bee an "target-problem"?
i try to compile vs. Android 2.2
i also tried to create a new AVD with Target "Google APIs (Google Inc)", but i cannot run my app with this AVD, don't ask me why :-((

i hope anybody can tell me how to solve this problem, thx in advance
if you want to have a look at my source, you can get it here:

http://www.marcusegger.de/examples/QuickPortfolio.zip

cheers, michbeck

Comment: you can use this link.
[Link]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile against "Android 2.2 Google APIs", not just "Android 2.2". You choose this in your IDE as the target Android platform.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Android but when I see your code I don't find the class which inherits 'MapActivity' class of Google map and run it on target GoogleAPI +Android 2.2