# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map application. I want to install it on a device having no maps library available.  Can't I burn in along the app.

Comment: See this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Comment: use this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't "burn in along the app", unless you're a pirate. Google Maps is software that is licensed by device manufacturers or is obtained from the Android Market. If a device does not have it, there is nothing you can do about that fact.

There is an undocumented `android:required` attribute on the `<uses-library>` element. However, we have been told it is safe to use, that it being missing from the documentation is merely a documentation bug. You can use `android:required="false"` to allow your app to run on a device that lacks Google Maps. This does not magically add Google Maps, though, and so if you try to start a `MapActivity`, it will crash. But, using `Class.forName()`, you can see if `MapActivity` exists, and if it does not, do something else for your maps (e.g., `WebView` and Web-based Google Maps, OpenStreetMap).

Comment: <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

still cant install