# I am getting following error in android

Tags: android

while using googleMaps i am getting error on console i.e

Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

please guide me what to do i changed sdk version in manifest file.

Comment: **Duplicate** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify in Android manifest file

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From Dianne Hackborn (Android Framework Engineer):

You have a `<uses-library>` line in your manifest for a shared library that is not built into the emulator.  The log will probably tell you more.

[Google is your friend](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7946cacd224ec31a)

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the incorrect Android API to run the program. To use Maps, you should use Google SDK not Android SDK