# application not installing on android simulator

Tags: android

I am trying to run an Android application.  When I install the application on the Android simulator, it shows this error in the console:

```
[2011-02-21 16:37:44 - TFLAPPv1] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2011-02-21 16:37:44 - TFLAPPv1] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-02-21 16:37:44 - TFLAPPv1] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Did you read that error message? It gives you a good hint where to investigate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Comment: give details about your project if any external library such google map if you are using..

Comment: @folone .. this could be possible answer.. :)

Comment: `Please check logcat output for more details` You can see your logcat by executing `adb logcat`.

Comment: How do you execute adb logcat?

Answer (score 4):

Open a command prompt and go to your platform tools folder

\Eclipse\sdk\platform-tools

There will be adb.exe there.  Type

adb logcat

Take a look at the output.  If you'd like further help, post the output on here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are using Google Maps in your application, and you are installing on an emulator AVD that does not have the Google APIs.