# getting error msg install failed missing shared library

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium

i have made one application which uses google maps APi,i am using titanium 1.2.2 and mobile sdk 1.5.1 for android,wenever i am trying to run the app on emulator,console shows an error

[INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

what does this error means and how to fix it??

Comment: i am using appcelerator titanium,cant add anything in manifest

Comment: I think you can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Comment: use follow link, should help  [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue.  Make sure you have changed the target from Android### to Google APIs in the AVD Manager.

1. Open Android SDK Manager
2. Select Tools -> Manage AVDs
3. Select a/the virtual device and click edit
4. In the target Select Google APIs...

If this target does not exist in the list, you need to install the Google APIs for the Level you require.

This will appear in the check list under the desired Level in the Android SDK Manager. Once this is installed (go grab yourself a coffee, it can take some time), repeat steps 1 - 4.

Comment: Btw do you know why do we need to do this?

Comment: @Pacerier Some apps use Google APIs in addition to the stock Android stuff.  For instance, you might have an app relying on Google Maps for the Play Store.

Comment: That's really helpful !

Answer (score 7):

You can add **android:required="false"** flag to your manifest file and the application should be able to start.

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false"/>
```

Then you have to make sure to protect your code from throwing an exception in places where you need it. You can try something like this to check if library is present:

```
Class.forName("com.google.android.maps");
```

Answer (score 4):

run android.exe or android.sh utility this will bring up the program to install android SDk. Go to third party add-ons and select Google Api's. After they have been deployed/installed. Please make sure to re-start adb. If you are prompted for a restart of adb. Please say yes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

between the `<application> </application>`

Tags of the Manifest.

Comment: I have done this but it has not worked as simply as I imagined

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your application requires a library that you either haven't included or your device doesn't have it.

Make sure you're using the Google API for Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

The usual suggestion to ensure you are running against a Google APIs android SDK is correct.

However, there is also a bug if you are using Titanium Studio whereby updating the SDK version in Titanium does not update the SDK in the actual android AVD. You will need to open the Android SDK Manager (SDK Manager.exe or SDK Setup.exe), select "Virtual Devices" on the left and then edit all appropriate devices to set their 'Target' to the desired SDK.

Answer (score -1):

I also came across this same problem and followed @CraigS steps but it didnt help.I was working on the emulator.

Then i tried uninstalling the app from the emulator and running the project again. It installed successfully. Just try this also if CraigS method doesn't help. :)