# unable to install android app - INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I am making an app which makes reference to Linphone app. I am sending an intent from a service in linphone to my app.

I installed Linphone on emulator (Android as well as Google API); but it installs erroneously  and doesn't start. Logcat shows `Cannot start linphone` error. Because of this, my app couldn't get installed. I get foll. error and installation stops:
`Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY`

So I installed Linphone on a device (Beetel android pad) and it works fine. After this, when I try to install my app, it fails to install. I am suspecting that it's the same problem as that in emulator. What can be the problem n how to solve it?

I have included `<uses-library android:name="org.linphone" />` in manifest file.
I checked on the net, but I found results which mainly talked about apps using Google Maps and people advised to use Google API Emulator. I tried that but it didn't help me as anyway I am not using any Google API/service.

Any help in solving this problem or giving some direction towards it will be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: Heyy guys, the issue is solved now! Solution was quite a basic thing.
My app was 2 n half MB in size. So I first uninstalled previous version of this app and then installed newly build version. So I guess there was some memory related problem, though I cant tell exactly how memory problem arose.

Thanks to all those who showed interest in this question! :)

Answer (score 2):

run android.exe or android.sh utility this will bring up the program to install android SDk. Go to third party add-ons and select Google Api's. After they have been deployed/installed. Please make sure to re-start adb. If you are prompted for a restart of adb. Please say yes.

I am not sure with the ans. BUt I got it from a link, where the problem is same as u have mentioned here.

## [getting error msg install failed missing shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375919/getting-error-msg-install-failed-missing-shared-library)

Comment: Thanks jyotiprakash for the help, but as I mentioned, I have tried this and my app doesn't make use of any Google service directly for which I need Google API emulator.