# Installation failed missing shared library error on micromax P300

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to install my application on Micromax P300 but it is giving me an error saying "INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY".
I know that this error comes when your application uses Google Map and your device don't have Google map.
But in my case i am using Micromax P300 TAB, and it has Google Maps also. but don't know why this error is coming.
Please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this

```
<application>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
....
</application>
```

in your manifest file

Comment: I have added this in my manifest file. but still the error is coming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375919/getting-error-msg-install-failed-missing-shared-library checked this?