# Install .apk file to Android Emulator on a Mac

Tags: android, macos, apk, adb

I'm new to Android and I was given some .apk files (not created by me) with malware that I'm trying to run on the Android emulator for testing purposes 
(trying to get app's system call data using strace).
I have checked several places online, but I'm stuck trying to install the .apk file. 
When I run the following command :

```
./adb install filename.apk
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153515/how-to-solve-install-failed-dexopt-this-error ?

Comment: @DuKes0mE yes I did, same error

Comment: I was having the same error. I solved it using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10368563/1760804

Answer (score 0):

Just Drag and drop apk into your Android emulator. its automatically install by it self.