# How to launch an existing app in Android emulator?

Tags: android

I have the code.google.com Android SDK, am able to launch the emulator and created a v3.0 object and its started and runs fine, but am just trying to "install" and launch an existing application.  its a database viewer with a .apk extension.  I have the source, but right now to start its a compiled app.

How is this done?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fire up your emulator (it has to be running when you do this), then open Terminal and type

```
>adb install your_program.apk
```

You have to cd over to the directory where the file is, first.

(the > is the terminal prompt... not a character you should be typing)

oh, and if you then want to uninstall it, you can do it right through the emulator, of if you know the actual package name you can then do it like...

```
>adb uninstall com.full.package.name
```

Oh, and I guess I'm giving mac advice cause I'm on a mac... if you're on a PC you'll use the command prompt... I'm assuming the rest is the same.

Comment: you need to connect to the device first.. "adb connect ip:port"

Comment: ah, ok i am trying the >adb and its not finding this as a command; now to try the adb connect ip, but not sure where this is run

Comment: oh, well that means that either you don't have Android on your system (unlikely if you have the Emulator running) or you never added the tools directory to your system PATH (much more likely).  What OS are you on?

Comment: oh, and connect is just another command for adb, so, once you have your system recognize where to go, you can run adb (in all its varied glory).

Comment: ok i found adb and tried using it, i have to CONNECT to the emulator device running first?  no matter what i type it isnt finding it.  i type adb devices and it shows emulator-5554.  so i type adb connect emulator-5554 and it says cannot connect to emulator-5554:5555   ok, connect emulator-5554:5554  cannot connect to emulator-5554:5554:5554   i also tried install, but... ok install by itself worked this time. wow! its trying to load.  now its saying INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY   ?

Comment: I just googled INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY and got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android  I think I should get my green checkmark now! :)