# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android

> "Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
>
> Please check logcat output for more details."

Problem is: There is no output at all in the LogCat output. Further this is not about some Google Maps library, which most questions here on SO are about[1]:
I'm trying to make use of my own library project.

my main project has following namespace: net.microtrash.cutoutcam

my library project has following namespaces, which I have referenced in the main app's manifest file:

```
<uses-library android:name="net.microtrash.lib" />
<uses-library android:name="net.microtrash.lib.button" />
<uses-library android:name="net.microtrash.cutoutcam.lib" />
```

Any ideas, why this error might happen?

[1] [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android)

Comment: Are the libraries in the Referenced Libraries folder?

Comment: There is a jar file with the referenced packages in it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> my library project has following namespaces, which I have referenced in the main app's manifest file:

Unless you built your own phone, or at least your own firmware, you do not have any of those libraries. You do not use `<uses-library>` for Android library projects.

Comment: You do not use <uses-library> for Android library projects.that's the point.thank you..

Answer (score 12):

The only solution which I have discovered is that whenever non-compatible Emulator is used for running Maps related Application, this problem always occurs. Simple solution is to run application on Google API emulator.

Comment: OH MY GOD. I couldn't install my app on a device because an incompatible emulator was running! Jeees. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `<uses-library>` tag for google-play-services, but I had `<uses-library>` tag for google maps as follows :

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

It worked. Most answers in Stackoverflow are with respect to Google-Maps v1. But I had this problem in Google-Maps-v2 and this trick fixed.