# Adding my own .jar into my adt project is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, libraries

I made library for my android games and i wanted to add it to another project to test how it works, but when i ran the application, it does not seemed to be able to find my library files(INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY). I have my library .jar in "libs" folder and i also have it added to my Libraries and Order and Export tabs in build path. In my manifest, i have  tag. I have Eclipse with ADT. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using **Google Maps** in your application?  If so, this may solve your problem: [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android)

You wrote:

> In my manifest, i have tag

If you are adding custom `uses-library` tags, that might be your problem.  See: [Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620774/installation-error-install-failed-missing-shared-library)

Comment: Nope, i am not using Google Maps.

Comment: Can you post the full error message you are getting in Eclipse?

Comment: I've added another possible issue to my answer.