# Building monodroid sample map applications

Tags: java, android, google-maps, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using the latest download of map sample application 'MapsAndLoactionDemo' from Xamarin and in Visual Studio 2010 I get the following compile error(s):

```
Error   10
Activate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object[]) in mono.android.TypeManager cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,java.lang.String,mapsandlocationdemo.MapWithOverlayActivity,java.lang.Object[])

mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("MapsAndLocationDemo.MapWithOverlayActivity, MapsAndLocationDemo, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    D:\Projects\Android\MapsAndLocationDemo\MapsAndLocationDemo\obj\Debug\android\src\mapsandlocationdemo\MapWithOverlayActivity.java   25  28  MapsAndLocationDemo
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Adding the line where the compilation error actually happens might help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **the google api** on your *emulator*
You can follow this: http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/MapsDemo/

> **Installing the Google APIs Android SDK add-on**
>  The Google APIs require the "Google APIs" add-on library, which is provided for each
>   API level. You need to download it for the API level you wish to
>   target.
>
> To install the Google APIs Android SDK add-on:
>
> 1. Launch the Android SDK manager: `$ANDROID_SDK_PATH/tools/android`
> 2. Within the Android SDK manager, click Available packages in the
>      left-hand pane.
> 3. In the right-hand pane, navigate to the tree view
>      node Third party Add-ons /Google Inc. add-ons (dl-ssl.google.com)
> 4. Select the check-box for e.g. "Google APIs by Google Inc., Android
>      API 8, revision 2".
> 5. Click the Install Selected button in the lower
>      right corner.
> 6. In the "Choose Packages to Install" dialog, select the
>      Accept radio button, then click the Install button.

If you're using **Genymotion emulator** [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android/7168399#7168399)