# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when using MapView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am trying to use a `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` in my app. It compiles without a problem, but I am getting the following error when launching it from Android Studio:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

I have tried everything in the [main thread for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android).

- I have installed the [Google APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhSLi.png)
- My build target is [Google APIs (4.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nIeJ.png)
- I have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps" />` in my AndroidManifest.xml file's `<application>` tag
- My AVD uses the [Google APIs target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsN6B.png)
- My real device has Google play services [installed and up-to-date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XK5AC.jpg)
- An error is also visible in the [preview pane of my activity file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2EZs.png)

If I remove the MapView reference and the `<uses-library>` tag, then the application launches.

This covers everything from the other threads that I can find on this topic. Does anyone know of anything else that might be causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

> I have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps" />` in my AndroidManifest.xml file's `<application>` tag

Delete that, as you made this up, and it is the source of your difficulty. Maps V1 used a `<uses-library>` element (with a different name); Maps V2 does not.

> My AVD uses the Google APIs target

Maps V2 is not supported in the emulator at this time.