# In Android, Not showing app after installed file into emulator. (from local hard-drive to emulator)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a problem:

I have a `SKKPMMC.apk` file on my local hard drive.

I've uploaded the file to the emulator, through the `push any file on to device` icon

But I can't find SKKPMMC on my emulator - it is not available in the menu list

Have any solution/steps ?

Comment: I had a similar issue where the app was not showing on the app list (but was present in Settings, Apps). Solved it by restarting the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

launch an emulator let it be online.
to check if it is online
(path_to_adb) dab devices

you will see the list of android devices(can be emulator as well).

(path_to_adb) adb install path_to_apk.

now check your emulator

this should work. happy coding

Comment: you got your answer, i told the same thing which you have accepted
Happy Chrismas

Comment: does not work for me, using the sample MyFirstApp given in the android getting started docs

Comment: when you did (path_to_adb) adb install path_to_apk
did you see what was the reply of cmd prompt,
whether installation successfully completed ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check your AndroidManifest.xml. Usually you should add the following action and category to one of your activities (the main entry point to your app).

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

The action tells the system that the activity associated with this action is a 'main' entry point in your app.

The launcher category says that the entry point should be listed in the (top-level) application launcher.

If this is not present in any of the activities in your AndroidManifest, you will face the issue, where you are unable to find the icon after installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows:**

1. Execute the emulator [(SDK Manager.exe->Tools->Manage AVDs...->New then Start)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVysAukOpCA)
2. Start the console (Windows XP), Run -> type **cmd**, and move to the **platform-tools** folder of **SDK** directory.
3. Paste the *APK* file in the 'android-sdk\tools' or 'platform-tools' folder.
4. Then type the following command.

   > adb install [apk file name]

   Example:

   > adb install Jorgesys.apk

**Linux:**

In Linux the adb file is found in platform-tools directory under the SDK root directory.

[**How to Install APK Files on Android Device Emulator**](http://blog.freewarelovers.com/2010/08/how-to-install-apk-files-on-android.html)

**Mac:**

```
PATH=$PATH:"adb location"
```

Example : PATH=$PATH:/users/jorgesys/eclipse/android-sdk-mac_64/tools

Then run adb.

---

for the problem which you have got do the following...
 I had the same issue.  Make sure you have changed the target from Android### to Google APIs in the AVD Manager.

1. Open Android SDK Manager
2. Select Tools -> Manage AVDs
3. Select a/the virtual device and click edit
4. In the target Select Google APIs...

If this target does not exist in the list, you need to install the Google APIs for the Level you require.

This will appear in the check list under the desired Level in the Android SDK Manager. Once this is installed (go grab yourself a coffee, it can take some time), repeat steps 1 - 4.

even, you can follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android)

Comment: Hi I belongs to windows platform. after adb SKKPMMC.apk installation at last i got this: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] What should i do? Thanks.

Comment: This happens when your application requires a library that you either haven't included or your device doesn't have it.