# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when try to run BasicHereMapsSolution

Tags: android, here-api, nokiax

So I'm trying to run BasicHereMapsSolution code sample in eclipse. I've already add com.here.android.sdk.jar to libraries in Java build paths. I also already set the emulator device to nokia X. But instead of working, I get message like this in console.

```
[2014-04-11 13:25:05 - BasicHereMapSolution] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2014-04-11 13:25:05 - BasicHereMapSolution] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-04-11 13:25:05 - BasicHereMapSolution] Launch canceled!
[2014-04-11 13:25:14 - Emulator] Error accepting connection, aborting
```

What possibly the problem?? Please help.

Comment: check: [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY error in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113088/install-failed-missing-shared-library-error-in-android)

Comment: Altough that link not exactly gives solution, but it gives me idea why it didn't work. So I must switch the target devices in AVD to Nokia X. Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you AVD:s build target is Nokia X. It should solve that problem.